# How to use go's json tag to unmarshal both numeric and string properties into a string value

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the following Go struct and JSON data:

```golang
type Entry struct {
    Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
    Value     string `json:"value"`
}
```

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "value": "a string" // but sometimes it's a number
}
```

Most of the time the `value` of the JSON data is of type `string` however sometimes it's of type `number`.

If it's a number the `json.Unmarshal` method returns an error like this:

`json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Entry.valueof type string`

Is there an idiomatic and straightforward way to overcome such an issue in Go or I should implement a custom unmarshalling method for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `interface{}` for `Entry.Value`, and the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package will choose the proper type at runtime: `string` for a JSON string, and `float64` for a JSON number:

```
type Entry struct {
    Timestamp string      `json:"timestamp"`
    Value     interface{} `json:"value"`
}

for _, s := range []string{
    `{  "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",  "value": "a string" }`,
    `{  "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",  "value": 12 }`,
} {

    var e Entry
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &e); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v %T\n", e, e.Value)
}
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/07lIOmOYEZ_K)):

```
main.Entry{Timestamp:"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", Value:"a string"} string
main.Entry{Timestamp:"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", Value:12} float64
```

Yes, then you will need a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get a typed value out from `Entry.Value`.

Another option is to use [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number) which may accommodate both strings and JSON numbers:

```
type Entry struct {
    Timestamp string      `json:"timestamp"`
    Value     json.Number `json:"value"`
}
```

Using this, the above example it outputs (this it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gYArIyA5LrE)):

```
main.Entry{Timestamp:"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", Value:"a string"}
main.Entry{Timestamp:"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", Value:"12"}
```

When using `json.Number`, you may access its value using [`Number.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number.String), or [`Number.Int64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number.Int64) or [`Number.Float64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number.Float64) which return an error if its value is not a number.

**One thing to note here:** if the JSON input is a string that contains a valid number, e.g. `"12"`, then `Number.Int64()` will not report error but parse it and return `12`. This is a difference compared to using `intefface{}` (where `Entry.Value` will remain `string`).

Answer (score 1):

Providing an alternative to icza's answer using a custom unmarshaller.

```
type Entry struct {
    Timestamp string     `json:"timestamp"`
    Value     EntryValue `json:"value"`
}

type EntryValue struct {
    string
}

func (e *EntryValue) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Simplified check 
    e.string = string(bytes.Trim(data, `"`))
    return nil
}

func main() {

    for _, s := range []string{
        `{  "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",  "value": "a string" }`,
        `{  "timestamp": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",  "value": 12 }`,
    } {

        var e Entry
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &e); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", e)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it superior to the other one using `json.Number`?

Comment: Just that a slight improvement in readability in my opinion. 
A `json.Number` type holding non-numeric string values could be a bit confusing for some readers.